# cryptsetup-reencrypt disk without data loss

Tags: luks

If someone has stolen the head of LUKS disk and hacked my LUKS passphrase, and I then change the passphrase, can the person still decrypt my data using the stolen head? If yes, what can I do to prevent this without losing data? `cryptsetup-reencrypt` looks like it might be the solution, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, any operation which involves moving a bunch of data around on disk, such as re-encrypting a LUKS container, has the inherent risk of data loss. The only measure you can take against data loss is to have a reliable backup.

> WARNING: The cryptsetup-reencrypt program is not resistant to hardware
>   or kernel  failures during reencryption (you can lose you data in this
>   case). ALWAYS BE SURE YOU HAVE RELIABLE BACKUP BEFORE USING THIS TOOL. - source: `man cryptsetup-reencrypt`

That said, yes the stolen LUKS header can be used to unlock the LUKS container. The reason is the passphrase(s) are never used to encrypt the data. Instead, a completely different encryption key is used. And this key is never changed; Unless you re-write the LUKS container, which is essentially what `cryptsetup-reencrypt` does. The passphrase(s) simply provides a way to access the real encryption key.